# Can't install NPM in cpanel with sharp any version

Tags: node.js, angular, cpanel, multer, sharp

I am using sharp to convert images to webp (project developped with angular + nodejs), it works only localy because i have error when i deploy using Cpanel (nodejs apps), i checked with different versions (latest 0.31.1, 0.27.0  and also 0.23.0 ..). I can install sharp if only i remove it from dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "sharp": "^0.27.0"
```

Have you any idea ?
Thanks.

Here is error :

> 

npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/xxx/nodevenv/nodejs_test/10/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary ....

> 

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "mysqlproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "sharp": "^0.27.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file": "^0.2.2",
    "material-icons": "^0.6.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.3",
    "nodemailer": "6.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "typeface-open-sans": "^1.1.13",
    "typeface-roboto": "^1.1.13"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false,
    "crypto": false
  }
}
```